why is pandoc --version command returning an error on Ubuntu 22.04
Hope I am not creating a double post. I checked but did not find.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo and I installed Pandoc by
sudo apt-get install pandoc (found it here )
Installation went without any error messages. Here is what the terminal showed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3 libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3 pandoc-data
Suggested packages:
  texlive-xetex pandoc-citeproc context wkhtmltopdf librsvg2-bin groff ghc nodejs php python r-base-core libjs-katex
  citation-style-language-styles
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3 libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3 pandoc pandoc-data
0 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 0 to remove and 22 not to upgrade.
Need to get 20,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 156 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3 amd64 0.29.0.gfm.3-3 [115 kB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3 amd64 0.29.0.gfm.3-3 [25,1 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 pandoc-data all 2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2 [81,8 kB]
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 pandoc amd64 2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2 [20,3 MB]
Fetched 20,6 MB in 1min 25s (242 kB/s)                                                                                                
Selecting previously unselected package libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 327293 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3_0.29.0.gfm.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3_0.29.0.gfm.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pandoc-data.
Preparing to unpack .../pandoc-data_2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking pandoc-data (2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pandoc.
Preparing to unpack .../pandoc_2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pandoc (2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libcmark-gfm0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.3-3) ...
Setting up libcmark-gfm-extensions0.29.0.gfm.3:amd64 (0.29.0.gfm.3-3) ...
Setting up pandoc-data (2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up pandoc (2.9.2.1-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...

When I ran pandoc --version I got this message
bash: /usr/local/bin/pandoc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

What might be wrong? What can I do to install pandoc without a hitch and use it?

You appear to have an incompatible version of pandoc installed in /usr/local/bin - which appears earlier in your PATH and is therefore selected before the one you installed using apt (which will be at /usr/bin/pandoc).

Thank you. That is strange. How can I purge that and install the right version?

First, verify that /usr/bin/pandoc --version works and gives the expected result. As to purging the incompatible version, it will depend how you installed it.

Well, I don't remember installing it. Simple, because I did know that such a thing existed. when I go into the directors I see three files
pandoc pandoc-lia pandoc-server

@Srinath that's curious, because pandoc-server and pandoc-lua only exist since pandoc 3.0, but your snippet above shows that apt installed pandoc 2.9.2.1. Somehow a new version of pandoc must have been installed. Do you use RMarkdown or Quarto?

@tarleb, Very strange. No I am not using Rmarkdown and I am not using Quarto. Only using the standard Markdown. Apart from that I use LaTex installed from the TeXLive DVD from DANTE

The reason it returns an error is because you have a custom installed version of Pandoc installed, which apparently does not work under your system.
The path returned by the error message, /usr/local/bin/pandoc, hints that this is a third party installed binary, i.e., a binary manually installed without using the package manager. The package manager will install executables in /usr/bin/.
A binary in /usr/local/bin/ will override any binary in /usr/bin/. Thus, when you execute pandoc, the system attempts to run the version in /usr/local/bin/.
Thus, delete the pandoc binary in /usr/local/bin/. You need to have root permissions to do this.
Thus, a different version of pandoc is installed on your system.  has higher prioritRemove the binary

may I delete both "pandoc" and "pandoc server" on /usr/local/bin ? If yes, I shall do that. After that, can I install usind sudo apt-get install pandoc?

This solved the question.
